# Can multiple web applications service one domain?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, routes

I maintain a fairly large ASP.NET MVC website that's running on the .NET Framework 4.7 and hosted by a dedicated IIS server that I administer. This lives at `example.com`.

I need to add a bunch of new functionality, and I'd like to do this using ASP.NET Core, so that I can be going with the newer technology to learn it and reduce my obsolescence exposure.

**BUT** I would like this to be invisible to the users of the existing site. Specifically, I want the new functionality to be accessible at `example.com/new-stuff`, so that it works the same as the `example.com/current-stuff` that they're used to, in terms of navigation and url structure.

Can I set up IIS or the app routes so that everything works as before, but a request for `example.com/{some-pattern}` is serviced by my new and different web app, while requests that don't match the pattern are serviced by the old app? Or is there some other way of accomplishing my requirement?

Comment: as i understood you want to replace some some url pattern to point to different application? try to create virtual folder inside your site pointing to different application (new ap-ppool would be good practice), but remember, since its a different app - you need to pass logged user authertication and authorization to child app

Comment: @PowerMouse: if that information all lives in cookies and the apps share a domain, would that still be necessary?

Comment: You might be able to do this with Application Request Routing, but I haven't used it very much to be able to say for sure. See: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with routing or redirection rules. I will set iis virtual folders, so no url pattern will change.

Comment: Can you do this so that the two apps share the same domain? Could you provide a little more detail about how you set this up, or links to documentation on this approach?